# Как парсить простую переменную в ExpressionEngine?

Tags: php, cms, codeigniter

Поставил хук на *channel_entries_query_result*. Мне нужно в функции выполняемой по этому хуку посчитать число записей и парсить это в виде переменно в шаблон. Может кто-нибудь подсказать как это сделать?

```
    function recently_viewed($obj, $query_result) {
        $variables = array(
            'real_total_result' => count($query_result)
        );
        if (array_key_exists('exp_recently_viewed', $_COOKIE)) {
            $limit = (int)$this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('recently_limit');
            $recent = array_slice(unserialize($_COOKIE['exp_recently_viewed']), -$limit);
        } else {
            $recent = array();
        }
        // Check for our parameter from the exp:channel:entries tag
        $recently_viewed = (bool)$this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('recently_viewed');
        // if parameter found
        if ($recently_viewed) {
            $recent_entries = array();
            foreach ($query_result as $entry) {
                if (in_array($entry['entry_id'], $recent)) {
                    $recent_entries[] = $entry;
                }
            }
            return $recent_entries;
        } else {
            return $query_result;
        }
    }
```

Вот, пытаюсь парсить переменную *real_total_result*, template engine ее успешно парсит, но что делать дальше? Если результат парсирования не вернуть, то эта переменная так и останется не замененной, но с другой стороны, мне обязательно нужно вернуть результаты sql запроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы это получилось в расширении нужно устанавливать дополнительный хук на парсинг шаблона. В моем случае получилось так:

```
    function activate_extension() {
        $this->settings = array();
        $data = array(
            'class'    => __CLASS__,
            'method'   => 'recently_viewed',
            'hook'     => 'channel_entries_query_result',
            'settings' => serialize($this->settings),
            'priority' => 10,
            'version'  => $this->version,
            'enabled'  => 'y'
        );
        $this->EE->db->insert('extensions', $data);
        $data = array(
            'class'    => __CLASS__,
            'method'   => 'get_real_total_result',
            'hook'     => 'template_post_parse',
            'settings' => serialize($this->settings),
            'priority' => 10,
            'version'  => $this->version,
            'enabled'  => 'y'
        );
        $this->EE->db->insert('extensions', $data);
    }

    function get_real_total_result ($final_template, $sub, $site_id) {
        return $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single('real_total_result', 9, $final_template);
    }
```